# Ejabberd crash when using mod_muc_admin

Tags: crash, ejabberd

We are compiling ejabberd 17.9 using Erlang OTP 20 and Elixir 1.5.2.

We are getting the following error when we try to use mod_muc_admin to remove unused rooms with history_size > 0:

```
:mod_muc_admin.rooms_unused_list("global", 1)
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in :calendar.datetime_to_gregorian_seconds/1

The following arguments were given to :calendar.datetime_to_gregorian_seconds/1:
 # 1
    {1513, 700515, 685388}

(stdlib) calendar.erl:137: :calendar.datetime_to_gregorian_seconds/1
```

I suspect this is related to Erlang/Elixir versions, but I did not found any official documentation that states any problem with the versions we are using.

The documentation of the erlang source code states:

https://github.com/processone/ejabberd

```
Erlang/OTP 17.5 or higher.
```

Any thoughts?

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by a bug in ejabberd.

It was corrected in commit:
https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/commit/5e4c547856de6624e4012eb3bf